# Generar numeros para una matriz en java

Tags: java, java-swing

Necesito generar numeros aleatorios del 3 al 10 en una matriz en de 8x8 sin que se repitan  y como la matriz es algo grande los demas numeros se deben colocar en 0

un ejemplo

```
{0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0}
{0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9}
{0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0}
{0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0},
{10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

Comment: Y cuál es el criterio para saber en que lugares deben colocarse los 8 números aleatorios?

Comment: O sea 8 numeros deben colocarse en cualquier parte de la matriz no importa donde, lo unico es que no deben repetirse, por ejemplo que hayan  dos 3, no, el unico numero que debe repetirse debe ser el 0, si me entiendes, tomemos como ejemplo que puse, supongamos que esa matriz se genero con los numero asi

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Vamos a darle vuelta al problema. Como yo lo veo, tu no necesitas números aleatorios del 3 al 10. Tu necesitas SIEMPRE esa secuencia de números, pero colocada de manera aleatoria dentro de la matriz de 8x8.

Lo que yo haría, entonces, es un ciclo que me va dando la secuencia de los números del 3 al 10, y para cada uno, genero una posición aleatoria y, si no está ocupada ya por otro número, le asigno el valor de la secuencia. Si ya está ocupada, repito el proceso hasta encontrar una que no lo esté.

En código, sería algo como:

```
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    int FILAS = 8;
    int COLUMNAS = 8;

    int[][] matriz = new int[FILAS][COLUMNAS];

    Random aleatorio = new Random();
    boolean asignado;
    for (int i = 3; i != 10; i++) {
      asignado = false;
      do {
        int fila = aleatorio.nextInt(FILAS);
        int columna = aleatorio.nextInt(COLUMNAS);
        if (matriz[fila][columna] == 0) {
          matriz[fila][columna] = i;
          asignado = true;
        } 
      } while (!asignado);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < FILAS; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNAS; j++) {
        System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + ", ");
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
    }
  }
```

Que me produce, por ejemplo, está salida:

```
0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 
6, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

Comment: Si amigo esa es, gracias, habia hecho algo asi pero me repetia los numero, buena solucion. Buen dia.

Comment: En la programación, como en la vida, para encontrar las _respuestas correctas_, primero debes aprender a hacer las _preguntas correctas_, o como algunos le dicen, pensar _out of the box_, que al final de cuentas es en buena parte tratar de ver el _problema_ desde todos los ángulos posibles para encontrar el más fácil de resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Para generar los números aleatorios podes usar `java.util.Random`

Este código guarda los 8 números aleatorios en un vector. 
Desde ahí los podés ubicar en la matriz aplicando tu propio criterio.

```
int [] aleatorios = new int[8];
Random random = new Random();
for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
    aleatorios[i] = random.nextInt(8) + 3;
}
```